# Hive / Hue view return all rows from newest partition (year / month / day)

Tags: sql, hive, bigdata, hue

I want to create a view that just selects the latest partitions' rows. I can do it by joining to a sub query that does a max on the values, but that takes very long. I was hoping I could load the result of show patitions into a table and then use that in the where clause somehow, but it becomes a mess.

Any elegant way of doing this?

Sample table (customer_usage) looks like this:

```
customer_id
event_id
load_year
load_month
load_day
total_usage
```

All ints.

`show partition customer_usage` returns:

```
>     2 load_year=2018/load_month=10/load_day=10
>     3 load_year=2018/load_month=10/load_day=11
>     4 load_year=2018/load_month=10/load_day=12
>     5 load_year=2018/load_month=10/load_day=13
>     6 load_year=2018/load_month=10/load_day=14
>     7 load_year=2018/load_month=10/load_day=15
>     8 load_year=2018/load_month=10/load_day=16
>     9 load_year=2018/load_month=10/load_day=17
```

Table format is parquet on hadoop.

Comment: Can you add the table structure and a sample query ?

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace view vw_customer_usage
as select * from customer_usage
where load_day >= current_date - 7
```

if you want the data for the last 7 days. Similarly, add where clause for month and year.

Answer (score 0):

You can try shell script to sort and get the last partition which will be your last partition.

```
hive -e "show partitions <table_name>" | sort -V | tail -1
```

I have tried using a table with 3 partitions (year, month, day) with string as the datatype. The above command fetched me the latest partition.

Hope this helps :)